# Node.js synchronous loop execution

Tags: node.js

**AWSERED DONT NEED TO WRITE**

How to make this loop run synchronous in node js

**CODE:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        inv(arr[i][0],arr[i][1]); 

  }
```

**inv(arr[i][0],arr[i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1y8L.png));** // this is a function which fetches data from a website must be executed one by one or ip will be blocked cant be executed async

What program does:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1y8L.png)

Comment: This will not run in parallel. What's the actual problem?

Comment: the program runs the function inv(arr[i][0],arr[i][1]); all together overloading the server and blocking my ip i want the program to run loop function one by one and wait for it

Comment: If the `inv` function is a promise, you can use `async/await`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function to sync the function execution

Comment: not a promise function its a normal function that returns nothing just saves data

Comment: `for( ) { }` is synchronous: each execution of the loop is done in sequence. I think it's likely that `function inv(a,b)` is using an asynchronous call to the website, so you will have to address the problem there. Without seeing the code of `function inv()` it's hard to give advice. One possibility would be to have `function inv()` use a synchronous call to the server - that is, it should not return from the call until after the server has responded. Or, have `function inv()` generate a queue of requests that are handled one-by-one by a different function.

Comment: yep found out the function is return to loop without completing so gonna make the function sync ty for answer

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the function it was async so i made it recursive to solve the problem